# Bootstrap button in nav with two words causes second word to wrap

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying to figure out how to get a navbar in bootstrap 5 to look normal with a "Log In" button. But the space causes it to drop "In" down to a second line making the navbar much longer than it is supposed to be. I'm not sure how to prevent it from happening. https://codepen.io/binarycode/pen/PobJvOR

Edit: A "-" between the words seems to cause the issue as well.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
    <form class="d-flex">
          <input type="email" aria-label="Email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="Email" size="25"
           value="{{ last_username }}" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control me-2" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" aria-label="Password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password" name="password"
           id="inputPassword" class="form-control me-2" required>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Your CodePen is leveraging Bootstrap 4.5.0, so my answer is two-fold...)*

---

**For Bootstrap 4** *(your CodePen example)*

Any reason you're using `<form class="d-flex">`??

Correct usage, according to [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/#forms), is `<form class="form-inline">`.  Use that and the wrap goes away.

If you must use "`d-flex`" then you need to inject 'white-space: no-wrap' in somewhere, e.g. like this:

```html
<button class="btn" type="submit" style="white-space: no-wrap">Log In</button>
```

---

**For Bootstrap 5** *(Specific to **Beta-2**)*

Although the [docs suggest](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#scrolling) that one should use "`d-flex`", this does not work with text that contains whitespace when the remaining content is perceived to be too small by the browser.

This was raised in issue [#32383](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32383) - and subsequently closed as fixed *(though plainly not)*.

That issue does however discuss the why's.  "`d-flex`" just sets the `display: flex` CSS .. that in turn enables a flex context for all its direct children.
As the form does not specifically define any further flex attributes .. the browser assumes wrapping if it sees fit.

A workaround to this is to specifically control the flex attributes - one that seems to work well *(and is mentioned in the issue)* is `flex-shrink-0`.  Apply that to your button and it should work:

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
    <form class="d-flex">
      <input type="email" aria-label="Email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="Email" size="25"
        value="{{ last_username }}" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control me-2" required autofocus>
      <input type="password" aria-label="Password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="current-password" name="password"
        id="inputPassword" class="form-control me-2" required>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success flex-shrink-0" type="submit">Log In</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vinorodrigues/h1dnuem5/6/)

*(Please make sure to let the BS5 authors know that the "fix" is not ... on the issue [#32383](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32383), and [#33184](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/33184).)*

Comment: Thanks, this is for Bootstrap 5 which recommends d-flex. Found out it's a known bug that needs to be fixed. But if anyone else is having this problem it can be fixed by using a non breaking space in between the words. - Log&nbsp;In

Comment: Indeed this is a know issue (see [#]()) and the Bootstrap authors have closed this as fixed (it's not).  I will amend the answer to reflect this.

Comment: * [#32383](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32383)

Answer (score 0):

Known bug in version 5. Can be fixed with non-breaking space. "&nbsp"